# How do I manipulate key, value pairs in JSON file?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON file that presents information like this for nearly 250 datapoints.

```
{'China': {'Content' : ['china', 'country', 'south', 'east', 'asia', 'most', 'populous']}}
```

I want it to become like this.

```
{'Title': 'China', 
'Content':['china', 'country', 'south', 'east', 'asia', 'most', 'populous']}
```

How do I do that?

I have already tried Dataframe methods but couldn't figure out.

How do I manipulate the key, value pairs in JSON file?

Comment: That's not valid JSON...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_dict = {'China': {'Content' : ['china', 'country', 'south', 'east', 'asia', 'most', 'populous']}}
result= []
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    result.append({'title':k, 'Content':v['Content']})
```

Comment: Result is a list here though. How about:

    result = dict()
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        result['Title'] = key
        result.update(value)

Comment: @N.Clarke I make the result as a list because OP said that he/she has 250 points like that. I was trying to show OP the usage of `append`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below code can help,

```
present_dict = {'China': {'Content' : ['china', 'country', 'south', 'east', 'asia', 'most', 'populous']}}
new_dict = dict()

for i,k in present_dict.items():
    new_dict['Title'] = i
    new_dict[next(iter(k))] = next(iter(k.values()))

print(new_dict)
```

output: {'Title': 'China', 'Content': ['china', 'country', 'south', 'east', 'asia', 'most', 'populous']}